# Digikam can't find my photos

Tags: restore, digikam

I recently upgraded my Linux system from Lubuntu 18.04LTS to 20.04LTS by making a tar backup and restoring it into the fresh install.  It did include config files but I opted when restoring to not include all of the hidden (.*) files.  I would like to do those individually.  When I open Digikam, it offers me a choice of migrating from 4.0 or a fresh 6.0 configuration, so I assume I've missed important config files.  I know I was using 6.0 before and was very happy with it.  I don't really want to migrate OR choose a new fresh install if I can just copy over the right files from the backup.  I'm assuming that perhaps the necessary files didn't get backed up -- can anyone out there tell me what files or folders I should check to ensure that I can start digikam where I left it?  I tried copying the .kde directory but that alone does not seem to have done enough.  What other files/folders should I restore to return my Digikam to what it used to be?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: From your choice of tar, I assume this is some kind of linux. How did you make the tar-backup. Does it include directories like ~/.config and ~/.kde?

Comment: Thank you, I have edited the original question to include more of that key info!  I am sorry to overlook that at the start!